# how do you get a div to render to the right?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a menu `div` to appear below the menu icon that I have but have it open up to the left.  The menu icon is on the top right of the screen, if the `div` opens to the right, it goes off the screen.

Does anyone know how to do this?  I have tried `float:right; position:relative/absolute; right:0px` but it doesn't move.

I have also tried:  `text-align:right` on the menu icon.  On roll over it pushes the icon to the right of the `div` which is what I want but after I `onmouseout` the icon goes back to where it originally rendered.

The following picture shows what it's currently doing:

[image: current broken example]

This shows what I would like the image to look like when the div renders, but not out of the header:

[image: what I want]

**HTML**:

```
<ul id="primary-nav">
    <li class='primary-link' style="text-align:right">
       <a id="lnkChannel" runat="server">
           <asp:image runat="server" id="menuImage" imageurl="Menu.gif"></asp:image>
       </a>
       <div class='secondary-nav-wrapper'>  
          <ul class='secondary-nav'>
             <li>
                 <a class="title-image">
                      <span class='block-green'>Main Header 1</span>
                 </a>
                 <div class="menu-column">
                      <ul class="tertiary-nav">
                          <li>
                              <a class="tertiary-title" href="">link 1</a>
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                 </div>
             </li> 
          </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
.header1 {
  max-width: 60px;
}
.header1 .main-nav #primary-nav {
  float: left;
}
.header1 .main-nav #primary-nav > li {
  float: left;
}
.header1 .main-nav #primary-nav > li .secondary-nav-wrapper {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border-top: 3px solid #35a096;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #35a096;
  display: none;
}
.header1 .main-nav #primary-nav > li:hover > a {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.header1 .main-nav .secondary-nav {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header1 .main-nav .secondary-nav:before,
.header1 .main-nav .secondary-nav:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.header1 .main-nav .secondary-nav:after {
  clear: both;
}
.header1 .main-nav .secondary-nav > li {
  border-right: 1px dotted #cccccc;
  float: left;
  margin: 6px 0 -5000px 0;
  padding: 0 6px 5000px 6px;
}
.header1 .main-nav .secondary-nav > li .title-image {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.header1 .main-nav .secondary-nav > li .title-image img {
  display: block;
}
.header1 .main-nav .secondary-nav > li .title-image .block-green {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.header1 .main-nav .tertiary-nav {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.header1 .main-nav .tertiary-nav li {
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.header1 .main-nav .tertiary-nav li a {
  color: #3a3a3a;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `padding-left`? And yes, providing us with some code would be useful.

Comment: @Marcel I added the html

Comment: No helpful to your question, but will help you in the future: http://getbootstrap.com/.

Comment: If you could add the CSS, that would be helpful as well. Really can't tell too much from just the HTML.

Comment: @StevenJohnson tried adding it but I cant get it to come out looking pretty.

Comment: @StevenJohnson there we go, pretty looking CSS.  Thank you all for your patience.

Comment: Tried out your code here http://jsfiddle.net/UsWyc/ and it gives a right aligned menu. Most probably you have some higher rules that conflicts. For more info please provide a link or a "working" fiddle.